# How to block database in rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, testing

There's a lot out there suggesting that it is a best practice to avoid hitting the database in Rails tests, aside from things like scopes and integration tests. Is there any way to block specs from making database queries? Something like a [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) for databases...

Comment: you should probably test against an actual database in your integration tests. You could use an embedded database, or use transactions and roll them back so you don't actually save to the database.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that in my question. Integration tests should hit the database, but in other more unit-like tests I'd like to be able to block it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a factory gem such as [Factory_Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) or [Fabrication](http://www.fabricationgem.org/) you have an option to use resource instances that are not saved to the database. For example in factory girl you can do the following:

```
# Returns a User instance that's not saved
user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)

# Returns a saved User instance
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

For more info on testing in rails check out:

- [Railscast #275](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test)
- [Everyday Rails Testing with RSpec - ebook](https://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec)

Comment: Yeah, I'm using factory girl, and `build` or `build_stubbed` wherever possible, but there are still places where my code might try save to the database, so I'd love to be able to block it out entirely.

Comment: I think the only way to block it out completely would be to use a database user on your test database with no write privileges. However, that would break your integration tests. I don't think that currently there is a way to do what you are asking, but if there is I'd be excited to know how.